# PHP display image based on positive or negative number

Tags: php

I need to display:

> /images/image1.jmp if the number is positive

or

> /images/image2.jpg if the number is negative

or

> /images/image3 if the number is 0.

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Offense</th><th>Previous Date Range</th><th>Current Date Range</th><th>Difference</th><th>Percentage Difference</><th>Up or down image in this column</></tr>";

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Offense']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PreviousDateRange']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['DateRange']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['difference1']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['percentchange']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['']. "</td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";         

 ?>
```

I found this code and have tried different ways if incorporating it in the `echo "<td>" . $row['']. "</td>` but not having any luck.

I get the code but can not manipulate it to fit what it needs to do. I'm sure it's a simple solution. Just frustrated.

```
switch ($myNumber) {
  case 0:
    echo "Zero is not a valid value.";
    break;
  case $myNumber < 0:
    echo "Negative numbers are not allowed.";
    break;
  default:
    echo "Great! Ready to make calculations.";
    break;
}
```

Thanks for the help guys. Got the answer that worked.

Comment: `case $myNumber < 0` is not valide .... do a simple `if..else` condition... and keep eyes open when reading [docs](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: What number are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry. The `$mynumber` isn't currently in my code. It's a snippet I found that I thought I could use. What I would like to happen is the $mynumber (or variation of it) should reflect the `percentagechange` in the column before. Hence, if the `percentagechange` is a positive number then an up arrow is displayed. If it is a negative number then the down arrow is displayed.

Comment: @macnotapplesessor see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a more readable solution.
I use an array to hold the links and use a calculation to see if it is negative or positive.

```
$img = ["-1" => "/images/image2.jpg", 
"0" => "/images/image3.jpg",
"1" => "/images/image1.jpg"];

$number = 0;

Echo ($number == 0 ? $img[$number] : $img[$number/abs($number)]);
```

https://3v4l.org/JstZl

If the number is positive the calculation will be `15/15 => 1`.
If the number is negative `-10/10 => -1`.

Edit:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Offense</th><th>Previous Date Range</th><th>Current Date Range</th><th>Difference</th><th>Percentage Difference</><th>Up or down image in this column</></tr>";
$img = ["-1" => "/images/image2.jpg", 
"0" => "/images/image3.jpg",
"1" => "/images/image1.jpg"];


while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Offense']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PreviousDateRange']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['DateRange']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['difference1']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['percentchange']."</td>";
    Echo '<td><img src="' . ($row['percentchange'] == 0 ? $img[$row['percentchange']] : $img[$row['percentchange']/abs($row['percentchange'])]) . '"></td>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Works perfect. Made some adjustments and it works absolutely perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us where `$myNumber` comes from so if the variable name is different just modify it in the code below.

```
echo '<td>/images/image' . ($myNumber == 0 ? '3' : ($myNumber >= 1 ? '1' : '2')) . '.jpg</td>';
```

Comment: Won't argue with you really but it is short, sweet and to the point (and solves the problem).

Comment: Yeah, the `$mynumber` isn't currently in my code. It's a snippet I found that I thought I could use. What I would like to happen is the `$mynumber` (or variation of it) should reflect the `percentagechange` in the column before. Hence if the `percentagechange` is a positive number then an up arrow is displayed. If it is a negative number then the down arrow is displayed.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, just substitute the correct variable name and what I gave you should do what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($myNumber < 0) {
    //show /images/image2.jpg
}
if($myNumber == 0) {
    //show /images/image3
}
if($myNumber > 0) {
    //show /images/image1.jmp
}
```

In your code:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Offense']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['PreviousDateRange']."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['DateRange']."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['difference1']."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['percentchange']."</td>";

  echo "<td>";
    if($row['percentchange'] < 0) {
      //show /images/image2.jpg
    }
    if($row['percentchange'] == 0) {
      //show /images/image3
    }
    if($row['percentchange'] > 0) {
      //show /images/image1.jmp
    }
  echo "</td>";

}
```

This is assuming, based off of your other comments, that `$row['percentchange']` is the number in particular that you care about checking against.